# XPATH - How to return result only if certain text present

Tags: xpath

How do I return this value (the URL) ONLY if it it present and has a number 1 in it:

```
    <div id="exid" class="example">
<a href="/example-url" class="exagain">1</a>
</div>
```

So if the code is as above I want this returned:

```
/example-url
```

If it is like the one below I don't want anything:

```
<div id="exid" class="example">
    <a href="/example-url" class="exagain">2</a>
    </div>
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example like this: `//div[@id = 'exid']/a[. = '1']/@href`.

Comment: Why do you test the id too? My suggestion: `//a[text()='1']/@href

Comment: @Jörg Because the OP delivered that as context, so I assumed it had some kind of significance.

Comment: Don't know what 'OP' is but if you are referring to my good self, you'd be right, I need to look for that exact class. Thanks again!